# Angular 2: why to use NPM manager instead of CDN references?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Angular 2 looks better and simpler than Angular, however, I have a problem using NPM - it is not allowed at my work. But the bigger question I have is why do we need NPM at all?
I have used Angular with CDN versions, which was always claimed to be better than a local version (better caching) so, what is the advantage of using NPM manager vs CDN references if any? Why grow a local size of a project?

Today I see WEB development uses NPM everywhere.
I want to understand WHY all of the sudden WEB development started to move toward local resources vs common, online resources.
I am looking for convincing explanations, good articles/blogs pointing to why chose one vs another.

Comment: not allow to use NPM is ridiculous. and there are plenty of blogs explains why js CDN libraries doesn't always have the benefits as they claimed.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have some strict privacy policy in my company and so far we can't use NPM because of some their EULA clause.

Answer (score 3):

One of the benefits of Angular is that the framework is structured in a way that allows you to tailor the application bundle to your specific application needs.

This is not possible with a one size fits all iife download from a CDN

If you look at the Angular npm packages you will see that they consists of a number of smaller modules that make up the framework.

Using a technique called "Tree shaking" your bundler can run static analysis on your code dependencies and create a bundle that only includes referenced modules. This can drastically reduce the bundle size.

Here is a some more info about Tree Shaking:

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/tree-shaking-in-javascript

Comment: I get the TreeShaking etc, but why the same things not to do with modules online? Why they must reside on my local server? If I make 5 alike projects I will have individual copies of their modules times 5. If I use CDN or use an online version, all 5 projects will be pointing to the same online source and have 0 local script.

Comment: The files have to be stored locally for you to be able to create an optimized bundle at "build" time.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly because a modern web app will use some kind of dependency or module loader, like requireJS or (in case of Angular2) SystemJS, or commonJS, and CDN sources make that more complicated, since it requires a new resource http connection to get your source asset, and from a different domain (crossserver scripting issues)

Comment: Isn't CDN (which stands for a content delivery network) can deliver the same, but online? I don't see why those modules should be local and not a reference to an online resource.

Comment: Yes you can in requireJS, which I use. But it is not allowed for making a build with the requireJS optimizer when used with "shim" dependencies, because it can't guarantee that the CDN resource will load before the buid.

Even if the config supports CDN, network connections will slow down your app loading if you really have all your 3rd-party libraries in CDN.